# Difference in HDFS data size and Hive Data Size

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hadoop2, apache-hive

I have a table in Hive.

When I ran the command `show tblproperties myTableName`, It gives below result:

```
numFiles        12
numRows         1688092
rawDataSize     934923162
totalSize       936611254
```

That means `rawDataSize is 934.92 MB and totalSize is 936.61 MB`

And when I ran command to calculate data size on HDFS table location for the same table.

```
[user@server1 ~]$ hdfs dfs -du -h -s /apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/myTableName
893.2 M  /apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/myTableName
```

The result data size is **893.2 MB**

I see that there is big difference in datasize here for the same table. I am trying to understand why there is difference in the data size here for the same table and looking for detailed explanation.

Table Type - **MANAGED_TABLE**

**# Storage Information**

```
SerDe Library:          org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe
InputFormat:            org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
OutputFormat:           org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
Compressed:             No
Num Buckets:            -1
```

Comment: All this formatting in the question for nothing :D

Comment: @philantrovert  I should have done more research before asking this. :P  I got confused from the result of online converter as by default it was showing in decimal,But yes, for me there was one outcome  that I got to know the difference between `rawDataSize` and  `totalSize` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

936611254 / 1024 / 1024 = 893.2 M

Comment: Thanks for the clarification,  my bad, I was using online converter to convert bytes in MB and by default It was showing in decimal. The actual result is in binary here.

Comment: more interesting question is, why the data gets increased after being stored in Hive? it's original (raw) size was `934923162` and in HDFS it is reflected as `936611254`